# CheckedListBox Item Selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have created a site that allows users to see a list of files that currently reside on my FTP site.

I have got the files appearing but when I select one and click download, it is not registering that I have selected an item.

At the moment I am using:

```
If CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox("A file needs to be selected...!")
End If

'NOTE - A SELECTION ISN'T BEING RECORDED BY THE PROGRAM!!'

If CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.Value <> "" Then
```

I think that it is not registering the selection being made, because the item being selected is not a string value.

But I am not sure what to set this as.

Comment: `MsgBox` in a WebApplication? Read [this](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Message-Box.aspx). You should provide more sourcecode, especially the part where you get the files and add them to the CheckBoxList. My assumption is that you are doing this also on PostBack and therefore overwriting the selection that was made.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided the actual code being used to attach the selection / change handler as well as the event method body.

I'm guessing your attaching to the checkbox SelectedIndexChanged event. If that's the case then make sure that you have actually bound a "value" to the checkbox list, ensure that you are using the "DataTextField"and "DataValueField" properties instead of just default binding the checkboxlist to a collection.